# Can BGP-LS provide an ip address as a node attribute when distributing IS-IS

Tags: cisco, bgp, is-is

I have an IS-IS network (all cisco) with a BGP router (cisco) that I am using to distribute the network link-state for monitoring / analysis. one thing I would like is to receive an IP address for each node so that I can query them with SNMP.

In the IS-IS LSP there is a routerIP attribute that is typically populated either by the loopback address of the router or the first IP address on the system.

The RFCs for BGP-LS indicate that for the Node NLRI there is a potential attribute that indicates the IPv4 routerID/IP of the node. But in the BGP-LS updates I am receiving this is not being provided (node name and area ID are though)

Is there a configuration on the BGP router that I need to set for this, or do IS-IS nodes just not provide an node IP on BGP-LS?